# How do I control my application's name in the UAC dialog?

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, uac

I would like to control the name of my application as it appears in the UAC dialog. Right now it shows up as something like "MyCompany.MyApp.exe"; I would prefer something like "MyApp Pro". In other words, I would like a short, friendly phrase instead of the raw EXE file name.

I noticed that MMC.EXE appears in the UAC dialog as "Microsoft Management Console", so it seems to be possible. But how?  There must be a build setting somewhere that controls this, I just can't seem to find it ...

**Edit:** The app is digitally signed.

Comment: or perhaps to something like "I'm not malware. Honest. These are not the droids you're looking for"

Comment: I'm looking for a legitimate way of changing the app's name, at build time presumably. I'm not trying to scam anyone.

Comment: @T.E.D. Trying to present your application with a human-readable name hardly turns your program into malware. If you look at your start menu, practically everything in it has "nice" friendly names, rather than just showing the executable name (Paint instead of mspaint.exe, for example). Does that mean mspaint is malware?

Comment: potential duplicate, but I like this answer more: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21702044/change-the-program-name-of-exe-on-uac

Answer (score 16, accepted):

After some experimentation, I've found that providing a `/d` switch argument to `signtool.exe` will do the trick. This works for binaries as well as Windows Installer databases (.msi files).

If no `/d` switch was provided, the UAC dialog uses the `FileDescription` field in the exe's VERSION resource.

For .NET apps, this is populated from the `AssemblyTitle` attribute.