# How to change auto generated program name in UAC during uninstall in Visual Studio setup project?

Tags: visual-studio, setup-project, vsinstaller

I have created a Visual Studio Setup project using Visual Studio 2015. When I install the setup in a Windows 7 machine the UAC prompt shows the actual program name when asking for permission to install. When I uninstall the program the UAC prompt shows a different program name when asking for permission to uninstall. Each time the program is installed the UAC prompt shows a different program name each time. Why does this happen ? How do I set my program name to appear in the UAC prompt during uninstall without it changing every time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that providing a /d switch argument to signtool.exe will do the trick.
Got my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1683160/how-do-i-control-my-applications-name-in-the-uac-dialog)